# Stateless component using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

My question is, can i get props from my father component if i am using redux with mapStateToProps. because im trying to pass props to my stateless component from my father component and just props from mapStateToPros are passed.

this is my call to the component

```
case ModalsEnum.ListaTransferenciaDeCasos:
      return (
        <ListaTransferenciasDeCasos
        openModal={(modalCode) =>
          this.props.openModal(modalCode)}
          />
    );
```

this is my stateless component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import '../../../assets/css/notification.css'
import { connect }  from 'react-redux';
import { ModalsEnum } from '../../../entities/ModalsEnum';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { transfereciasDeCasos: state.TransferenciaDeCasos.transferenciasDeCasos }
}
interface NotificationProps {
    transfereciasDeCasos:any,
    openModal: (modalCode: number) => void;
}
const Notification_ = ( props: NotificationProps ) => {
    const { transfereciasDeCasos, openModal } = props;
        return(
                    <button className="btn btn-default btn-notification" type="button" onClick={() => openModal(ModalsEnum.ListaTransferenciaDeCasos)}>
                        <img className="" src={require("../../../assets/icons/file-icons/svg/ic_notifications_24px.svg")} alt=""/> <span>{transfereciasDeCasos.length}</span>                          
                    </button>
        );
    }

const Notification = connect(mapStateToProps)(Notification_)

export default Notification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapStateToProps also passes the ownProps. You can access them like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
     transfereciasDeCasos: state.TransferenciaDeCasos.transferenciasDeCasos,
     ...ownProps
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that way just works with stateful components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The props you are passing to the child component will automatically be the part of the `props` object.